キーボード入力が「ひらがな」モードになってしまう
パソコンに Ubuntu 22.xx をインストール後、英語と日本語のパッケージをインストールしました。しかし日本語でタイプができなかった。
それで、Japanese（Mozc）も追加して、やっとひらがなでタイプができた！
けれども、キーボードで例えば「D A」を打つと「だ」ではなくて「しち」が入力される。このような全部のキー。Qは「た」、Rは「す」とか。
どなたかこういう問題が起きたことある？それと解決方法がどうしたらよろしいでしょうか？

物理的なキーボードについてもUS/日本語どちらの配列を使用しているか記述しておいた方が良いと思われます。あと何かの仮想化ソフトでゲストOSとして動作させているなら、ホストPC&OSと仮想化ソフトの名称も記述しましょう。まあ日本語キーボードを使っていて DA→しち、Q→た、R→す であれば「ひらがな入力モード」なのは一目瞭然なので、それを思い付かないならUS配列キーボードを使っているのだろうなとは思いますが。こんな記事とか参考になるのでは？ Ubuntu22.04＋Mozcで英語キーボードを利用している時に日本語入力と英語入力を切り替える, Ubuntuでローマ字入力したいのにかな入力しかできない あるいはそれらをキーワードにもっと検索してみてください。

はじめから日本語環境の設定がされている 日本語Remix を使う、という選択肢もあります。

「Mozc の設定」で変更できます
Ubuntuで GNOMEデスクトップなら, 左下辺り「アプリケーションを表示」から一覧を出し
m とか mo とかタイプすれば現れるはず

Mozc プロパティ・ダイアログがでたら
[一般]タブ内「ローマ字入力・かな入力」の項目を変更してみてください

